# Postgres not working? Anyone? SQL commands?

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
PS C:\Users\Lord> psql -U postgres

Password for postgres user:
```

```
psql (16.2)
WARNING: The console code page (850) differs from the Windows code page (1252)
              8-bit characters may not work correctly. See the page
              psql reference "Notes for Windows users" for details.
Type "help" to get help.

postgres=#help
You are using psql, a PostgreSQL command-line client.
Type: \copyright to show distribution terms
          \h for help with SQL commands
          \? for help with psql commands
          \g or end with a semicolon to execute the query
          \q to exit
postgres=# \h
'more' is not recognized as an internal command
or external, an operable program or a batch file.
```

I installed PostgreSQL (latest version) I can locate it, create a database, but if I want to do some command, for example:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name;
```

the above error occurs
​

Comment: This error message does not mean your postgres DB does not work; also, the error message you shared does not occur when you type a query but when you type `\h`... If all you want to do is a `SELECT` query, how about using a window-based SQL client? You can google for several choices, e.g. https://www.pgadmin.org/

Comment: This question is about psql, the SQL client for PostgreSQL. Check the manual: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html

Comment: How did you install Postgres?